# Batch rename files replacing non-alphanumeric characters with underscore

Tags: bash, macos

I would like to recursively rename several files located in all subdirectories of a parent folder. I would like to remove spaces and other non-alphanumeric characters and replace them with an underscore.

I have looked at several command such as `tr`, `for f in *`, and `rename` but I'm still having struggles trying to accomplish this recursively.

How can I go about doing such a rename recursively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're talking about "recursively" then `find` comes into play.

```bsh
cd /path/to/parent_folder
find . -depth -exec do_stuff_here +
```

I'm using `-depth` so that files in a subdirectory get renamed before the subdirectory itself,
and `-exec program {} +` so that the program receives many filenames at once, reducing startup overhead.

Since there's no builtin rename utility that ships with the mac, I'll wrote `do_stuff_here` as a bash script

```bsh
bash -c '
  for file; do
    tail=${file##*/}                         # part after the last slash
    alnum_only=${tail//[^[:alnum:]]/_}       # replace characters
    mv -v "$file" "${file%/*}/$alnum_only"
  done
' sh file ...
```

That trailing "sh" is required for `bash -c '...'` one-liners -- the first argument is taken as `$0` and the rest of the arguments are $1 etc

Putting it all together:

```bsh
find . -depth -exec bash -c '
  for file; do
    tail=${file##*/}
    alnum_only=${tail//[^[:alnum:]]/_}
    mv -v "$file" "${file%/*}/$alnum_only"
  done
' sh {} +
```

Other notes:

- this solution does not take care of file extensions: `file.txt` will turn into `file_txt`.

  - if this is a problem, change `${tail//[^[:alnum:]]/_}` to `${tail//[^[:alnum:].]/_}` -- adding a dot to the characters to keep.
- Have you thought about what should happen if two different files_with_special_chars both map to the same destination file?

  ```
  ./subdir/file_1
  ./subdir/file-1
  ```

  With my solution, only the contents of the last file will remain.